# JavaScript to hide <li> tag if user is online

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this JavaScript that works outside of the

tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('1234', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_1234'));
liveagent.showWhenOffline('1234', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_xxxx'));
});</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2-c1cs-ord.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/42.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.init('https://d.la2-c1cs-ord.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '12345', '123456');
</script>
```

I would like to show the li with the id of "menu2"  only when the liveagent.showWhenOnline is true.

Here is the menu:

```
<div id='cssmenu' align="center">
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Admission Requirements</span></a></li>

    <li><a href='#'><span>Financial Aid/Scholarships</span></a></li>

    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>FAQs</span></a></li>


</ul>

</li>


    <li class='has-sub'><a><span>Re-Enroll students </span></a></li>

    <li class='has-sub'><a><span>Parent Resources</span></a></li>

    <li class='has-sub'><a><span>Meet the Staff</span></a>

<ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Admissions</span></a></li>

    <li><a href='#'><span>Financial Aid</span></a></li>

    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Student Ambassadors</span></a>
</li>


</ul>

    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Request Information</span></a></li>


    <li class='menu2' style="border: 0px none; cursor: pointer" onclick="liveagent.startChat('1234')">menu 2</li>

</div>
```

Let me know if that makes sense!

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/soe/4669486 ... you should use 2 different elements to `showWhenXxline`

Comment: `JavaScript != Java`!

Comment: My apologies. Had a typo on the thread. in the javascript, they are two different elements now. It will work when I use other elements that are not LI. I have also tried div tags and had no luck. Any thoughts

Comment: It does not seem to work in the li tag. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the element by id, the current code won't work since you have set the `class="menu2"` and not id.

**Try changing**

```
<li class='menu2' style="border: 0px none; cursor: pointer" onclick="liveagent.startChat('1234')">menu 2</li>
```

**to**

```
<li id='menu2' style="border: 0px none; cursor: pointer" onclick="liveagent.startChat('1234')">menu 2</li>
```

If this doesn't work, share the code you have till now or a working codepen link.